# OCX/COM: Some methods do not show up in PowerShell

Tags: com, powershell, ocx

I have the ActiveX control SetACL.ocx. It is registered on my system and I can use it from C# (Visual Studio 2010) without problems. Visual Studio's Object Browser displays all methods.

In PowerShell, however, about a third of the methods are not displayed. If I try to call one of the missing methods I get MethodNotFound:

```
PS C:\> $setacl = New-Object -ComObject setacl.setaclctrl.1
PS C:\> $setacl | Get-Member

   TypeName: System.__ComObject#{85869435-0ee3-440b-bf69-6c52c6638073}

Name                   MemberType Definition
----                   ---------- ----------
AddACE                 Method     int AddACE (string, bool, string, int, bool, int, int)
AddDomain              Method     int AddDomain (string, string, int, bool, bool)
AddTrustee             Method     int AddTrustee (string, string, bool, bool, int, bool, bool)
GetLastAPIError        Method     int GetLastAPIError ()
GetLastAPIErrorMessage Method     string ()
GetLastListOutput      Method     string GetLastListOutput ()
GetResourceString      Method     string GetResourceString (int)
Reset                  Method     void Reset ()
Run                    Method     int Run ()
SetAction              Method     int SetAction (int)
SetListOptions         Method     int SetListOptions (int, int, bool, int)
SetLogFile             Method     int SetLogFile (string)
SetOwner               Method     int SetOwner (string, bool)
SetPrimaryGroup        Method     int SetPrimaryGroup (string, bool)


PS C:\> $setacl.SetObject("test", 1)
Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject#{85869435-0ee3-440b-bf69-6c52c6638073}] doesn't contain a method named 'SetObject'.
At line:1 char:18
+ $setacl.SetObject <<<< ("test", 1)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (SetObject:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

**Any clues as to why PowerShell does not show all available methods but Visual Studio's Object Browser does?**

I tried both the 32- and 64-bit versions of PowerShell.

**Update 1:**

Here is the signature of one of the missing methods from the ODL file (yes, I have the full source code of the OCX, I am its author):

```
[id(2), helpstring ("Set the object on which all actions are to be performed")]
LONG SetObject(BSTR sObjectPath, LONG nObjectType);
```

**Update 2:**

Here is the [source code of the OCX](http://setacl.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/setacl/code/interface-activex/), directly browsable on sourceforge.

**Update 3:**

The OCX can be [downloaded from sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/setacl/files/). It is included in the file SetACL 2.2.0.zip.

**Update 4 - possible solution:**

Changing the methods with the DISPIDs 1-7 to higher DISPIDS and introducing 7 new dummy methods with DISPIDS 1-7 seems to do the trick. Now everything shows up in PoSh - except the dummy methods.

Does anyone have an explanation for this?

Comment: Can you give us the signatures of some of the missing methods?  That might provide a clue.

Comment: @OldFart: Added signature of one method and full source code.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the IDL file from the project [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/setacl/files/), it appears that every member of your _DSetACL interface with DISPID below 8 is being ignored.  Maybe try starting the DISPIDs at a higher index, like 100?  I do recall some "magic" dispid values, but I thought they were extremely high values, not low values, could be wrong...

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, but I just incremented the DISPIDs so they all are larger than 100, but again, no change...

Comment: Yes, I registered it (Visual Studio does that when building the OCX). I can use it from C# without any problem.

Comment: Played around some more and found out that always the first seven methods are omitted in PoSh. But it was not sufficient to just increase all DISPIDs, I had to introduce seven dummy methods to show up everything in PoSh.

Comment: :\  curious what would happen if you create a new OCX project with 8 methods... that is, is this isolated to SetACL, the general project type, or what...

Comment: For other OCX that seem to work fine, do they have 7 special methods that you wouldn't want to run?  Maybe PS is assuming there are some "internal" (for lack of a better term) members that show up first but you can't filter out by a simple pattern?

Comment: again, any special DISPID are high values not low.  this is just wonky.  you created a new ocx using the same framework?

Answer (score 0):

Try the -force parameter to Get-Member?

Total guess BTW...

Comment: -Force just gives me the following additional members: pstypenames, psadapted, psbase, psextended and psobject.

Answer (score 0):

Try Get-Member -Static? Guess again.

Comment: No, unfortunately does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Another stab in the dark...

```
Get-Member -Force -View All
```

Also make sure you are getting the right version of object.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing usually happens when there is no type library. When that happens you usually try something like this:

```
$bindingFlags = [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod
[System.__ComObject].InvokeMember('SetObject', $bindingFlags , $null, $setacl, 
                                  @("test", 1))
```

Comment: But there is a type library. And I am the author of the OCX, I can change anything I want to make this work as it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like PowerShell specific limitation. There are two workarounds mentioned [in the blog here](http://abhishek225.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!13469C7B7CE6E911!165.entry?sa=143237933).

Comment: Thank you, but I am not looking for a way around this limitation in PowerShell but instead how to (re-)write the OCX so that PowerShell can work with it properly.

Comment: Have you considered filing a bug with Microsoft Connect? Or, ask on the PowerShell Community forum? I would be very surprised if you didn't get a quick reply from someone on the PowerShell team.